# JavaScript select date between

Tags: javascript, xml, date

I have this JS code which pulls data out of xml table

```
GDownloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxm1l.php", function(data) {
          var xml = GXml.parse(data);
          var markerid = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
          for (var i = 0; i < markerid.length; i++) {
            var type = markerid[i].getAttribute("type");
            //var point = new GLatLng(parseFloat(markerid[i].getAttribute("lat")),
                                    //parseFloat(markerid[i].getAttribute("lng")));
            var date = markerid[i].getAttribute("date");

            //tabelis punkt "point" stringiks, keskelt pooleks ja 2 uut väärtust markeri atribuutideks
            var punktx = markerid[i].getAttribute("point");
            var kommentaar = markerid[i].getAttribute("kommentaar");
            var punkt = punktx.toString();
            var temp = new Array();
            temp = punkt.split(",");
            var point = new GLatLng(temp[0],temp[1])


            var marker = createMarker(point, date, type, kommentaar);
            map.addOverlay(marker);
          }
        });
```

How can I do so, that when I press a button, the script only takes data entered between certain time/date?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the date/time format in the XML, this is very simple:

```
for (var i = 0; i < markerid.length; i++) {
    var date = markerid[i].getAttribute("date");

    if (date >= fromDate && date < toDate) {
        // etc etc
    }
}
```

This would require the `date` attribute (and both `fromDate`/`toDate`, of course) to be a string in a string-comparable date-format (like `"yyyy-dd-mm hh:nn:ss"`).

If this is not the case, you probably must convert them to Date objects first, the comparison stays the same.

Comment: But can I also have "fromDate" and "toDate" be changeable variables? When I press a button, they would change accordingly, just like PHP-s $POST method. And is it possible that, when "date" is not between "fromDate" and "toDate" the whole cycle step will be ignored?